# In this phrase should I use `what you mean` or `what do you mean`?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

In this phrase should I use `what you mean` or `what do you mean` ?

> If it is possible, please explain what you mean by "doing this."
> Because I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

**What you mean** is generally the start of a statement:

"What you mean to do is outside the law."

**What do you mean?** is a question on its own in response to something, or part of a larger question.

As questions:

He:  "I'm already married, I'm sorry."
She: "What do you mean?"

"What do you mean by leaving the college at night to see a friend?"

The expression **What do you mean?** can be used either seek an explanation of a person's words or a person's actions/conduct, depending on the context.

So, it's clear that you need to omit **do** in the example you give.

Comment: If a person told me, "Don't you get bored doing this?" then can I say, `If it is possible, please explain what you mean by "doing this." Because I don't understand.`

Comment: You could ask them a direct question "What do you mean by _doing this_?" or an indirect question "Please explain/tell me what you mean by _doing this_".

Comment: @KateBunting Bunting Can you explain to me what "Don't you get bored doing this?" means?

Comment: "Don't you find it boring to do [whatever the person is doing at the time the question is asked]?"

Comment: @Kate Bunting Is this the same as saying, "Do you ever get tired of doing this?"?

Comment: Asking 'Don't you...?' implies that you think they probably do.